# Increasing font size of root element in javascript based on current size (of root element)

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I am using rem units to define font sizes in my CSS and I would like to use javascript to present the end user the options to change font sizes.

I can use pre-defined font-sizes and change the font-size using the following function:

```
document.documentElement.style.fontSize = "67.5%"
```

What I want to do is change the font size as a factor of the current font size. Basically something like the following:

```
document.documentElement.style.fontSize = Number(document.documentElement.style.fontSize) + Number(5) + "%"
```

How do I go about achieving this?

Fiddle for playing around: http://jsfiddle.net/rahulthewall/wX94C/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as rem units are based on the `font-size` of the `<html>` element in your case, you should be able to change that `font-size` and watch the rest of the font sizes change as well.

I was able to use this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery('html').css('font-size', '24px'); });
```

(`24px` can be replaced with any size.)

Comment: The problem is not in changing the font size, the problem is in changing the font size in relation to the current font size. I want to increase the current font size by 10% (for example). How do I do that?

Comment: You can use `parseInt( jQuery('html').css('font-size') )` to get the existing `font-size` and then use that as a reference. Here is an updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wX94C/2/).

Answer (score 7):

pure javascript would be something like

```
var root = document.querySelector(":root");

root.style.fontSize = "25px";
```

update: using  [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle)

```
    var root = document.querySelector("p"),
       style = window.getComputedStyle(root, null).getPropertyValue('font-size'),
    fontSize = parseFloat(style);

root.style.fontSize = (10*fontSize)+'px';
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/S4weS/)

Comment: The problem is not in changing the font size, the problem is in changing the font size in relation to the current font size. I want to increase the current font size by 10% (for example). How do I do that?

Comment: well if this is what you are looking for please accept the answer!

Comment: Hi, I accepted the jquery answer and I can only mark one answer as accepted (though in this case both answers are correct). Sorry.